# Saber asginaturas aprobadas

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda sobre cómo saber que número de asignaturas no aprobaron X estudiantes. Esto lo quiero hacer con arreglos o matrices en `Java`. es decir que a cada alumno le pueda asignar las materias en este caso 5 y las respectivas calificaciones.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: @jasilva hasta el momento tengo organizado los nombres de los estudiantes en arreglos, y las materias. pero no se como relacionarlos, es decir. Que la calificacion y cada una de las materias se las asigne a un estudiante...

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye toda la información relevante para comprender tu problema. Esto es: información sobre el proyecto, código relevante para comprender tu problema, mostrar lo que quieres lograr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que crees dos clases una para los alumnos y otra con las materias.

```
 public class Alumno{
     private String nombre;
     private Asignatura [] asignatura;

}

public class Asignatura{
     private String nombAsignatura;
     private Int nota;
}
```

En la clase "Asignatura" generas los métodos get() para el nombre de la Asignatura y la nota, y los llamas en la clase Alumno. Una vez que creas el alumno con una asignatura y nota, lo único que debes hacer en la clase que lo utilizas es decir declarar un array de tipo "Alumno", ejemplo:

```
 Alumno [] alumnos =new Alumno[30];
 int nota=alumnos[1].getNota();
```

Eso te da la nota del alumno para ese valor del array, puedes perfeccionar esto con métodos de búsqueda para el nombre o para aumentar el tamaño del arreglo de las asignaturas de un alumno. Espero te sirva o comentes alguna duda.